# Migrate from O365 Planner to Azure Boards

Tags: migration, task, azure-boards, microsoft-planner

Planning to move from O365 to Azure boards. Is there a way to migrate to Azure boards without importing CSV files?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct integration between Azure DevOps and Planner today. For limited amount of data (e.g. few plans), you can [export the Plans to Excel in Planner](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/export-a-plan-to-excel-4d850c6e-e548-4aab-83b4-b62b68662d2a), then make the column adjustments in Excel to what Azure DevOps requires, then save the content in csv file format, which should allow easy imports.

Edit: Actually, looking at the documentation, [Azure DevOps can import from Excel directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process). The import from Excel has more features, so you can export to Excel then import without converting to CSV: